# A question on density of double cosets in $\mathrm{SL}_2$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, dynamical-systems

Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G = \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and consider the subgroups
$$
N^- := \Bigl\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ x & 1\end{pmatrix} : x \in \mathbb{R}\Bigr\}
$$
and
$$
A^+ := \Bigl\{ \begin{pmatrix}e^\tau & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-\tau}\end{pmatrix} : \tau  \geq 0\Bigr\}
$$
and
$$
P := \Bigl\{ \begin{pmatrix}* & * \\ 0 & *\end{pmatrix}  \in G\Bigr\}
$$
Then one knows that $U := N^- P$ is dense and open in $G$ and $\Gamma u (A^+)^{-1}$ is dense in $G$ for all $u \in U$. My question is:

> Given $g \in G$,  can we construct sequences $(a_n)_n$ in $A^+$, $(\gamma_n)_n$ in $\Gamma$ and $(u_n)_n$ in $U$ such that the following holds?
>
> - $\gamma_nu_n^{-1}a_n^{-1} \to g$
> - $u_n \to e$

A statement like this is used in Mostow's book *Strong Rigidity of Locally Symmetric Spaces* in the proof of Lemma 8.5 on page 65 without explanation. However, starting with a sequence $(u_n)_n \to e$, I can not see how to get the sequences $(\gamma_n)_n$ and $(a_n)_n$ in a uniform way.

Edit: I have now written down the question with specific groups.

Comment: If $U$ is an open and dense subgroup, then $U=G$, right ?

Comment: @user120527 Yes, you are right if $U$ is a subgroup. I have now edited the question to use the same groups as Mostow. Hope its clear now.

Comment: Your $N^-$ is miswritten... probably the second diagonal entry should be 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @YCor Thank you. I have fixed it.

Comment: I suspect there is still a problem with your question. It is not true that $\Gamma u (A^+)^{-1}$ is dense for all $u\in U$ when $\Gamma$ is a lattice. What is true is that $\Gamma x N^-$ is dense (for any $x\in G$) if the lattice $\Gamma$ is cocompact (a Theorem of Hedlund).

Comment: @user120527 Oh yes, you are right. This might be the point. It is true however, that $\Gamma u(A^+)^{-1}$ is dense for *almost all* $u \in U$ according to this result: https://imgur.com/a/CaIoY28  taken from Proposition 1.5 on page 114 of the book from Bekka and Mayer. Actually, the statement in my question is used to proof Hedlunds theorem for cocompact $\Gamma$.